# excel pivot table - query based on mulitple columns value

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

I have a pivot table in excel that has an attribute say animals that holds 3 values (dogs, cats, birds)
and the rows represent persons.

```
    |dogs|cats|birds|
----------------------
John|    0|   1|    1|
Jack|    1|   1|    1|
Jim |    0|   0|    1|
Pam |    1|   0|    1|
Tess|    2|   1|    0|
```

I'd like to select all persons who have at least a dog and a cat, or exactly 2 dogs and a bird...
I am trying to use calculated fields but I can't seem to be able to select the proper values

```
=IF(AND(animals['dogs']>1, animals['cats'] >1),"YEAH", ":-(")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok that was fairly easy after figuring out what to search for
I user **calculated item** and I was able to right the exact formula I was looking for